# Append to an array by Parsing Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, angular

Trying to retrieve the Json string from `localStorage` and append a new dish to it. It is not working as it should, can someone please help me. Am using `TypeScript`.

```
interface Dish { 
    id: number;
    name: string;
    desc: string;
    price: number;   
};

export class BasketService {
    private BASKET: string = 'basket';

    log(dish: Dish) {

        var dishList: Dish = [];

        if (!localStorage.getItem(this.BASKET)) {
            dishList.push(dish);    //push the first dish (if local storage is empty)
        }

        //Append an injected dish to the existing local storage.
        dishList.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.BASKET)));
        dishList.push(dish);

        localStorage.setItem(this.BASKET, JSON.stringify(dishList));
    }
}
```

**Expected behavior:** Once the Dish is appended nicely, then it should be stored in the localStorage for further manipulation.

Comment: what is the expected behavior?

Comment: added expected behavior to the question.

Comment: according to your code it should be added. However, previous array structure is ruined. `array1.push(array2)` doesn't do what you expect. `array1 = array1.concat(array2)` is what you're looking for

Comment: besides, for the empty `localstorage`, `dish` is added twice

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the dish being added twice.

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in javascript require a different operation to be concatenated. `array1.push(array2)` pushes array as an object (1 item) into `array1`.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [4, 5, 6];
array1.push(array2);//[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

In javascript there is a function `Array.prototype.concat`. Should look like `array1 = array1.concat(array2)`. Note, that `concat` doesn't modify the array it is called on. rather it returns the new array.

Besides, in your posted code for the empty `localStorage`, `dish` is added twice 
I'd make it something like below:

```
   var json = localStorage.getItem(this.BASKET);
   if (!json) {
       dishList = [dish];
   } else {
       dishList = JSON.parse(json);
       dishList.push(dish);
   }
   localStorage.setItem(this.BASKET, JSON.stringify(dishList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, on doing JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem) we normally get a JSON object.
and it's value will be a array like example.

```
var dish = [];
var test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dummy"));
// test = {a : ['aa','bb','cc']}
dish = test.a;
dish.push('dd');
test.a = JSON.stringify(dish);
localStorage.setItem("dummy",test);
```

We need to follow this.

But I think you are directly pushing the object into the Dishlist which might be causing the issue.

The example is in pure javascript as I don't much exposure to Typescript.
Hope this helps you.